# How to disable FULLScreen mode when run MPMoviePlayerViewController in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, mpmovieplayercontroller

I have a problem : I added `MPMoviePlayerViewController` to `detailView`, but when i click on button to open `detailView`, `MPMoviePlayerViewController` auto play in FUllScreen mode. Now i want when click on button to open `DetailView`, `MPMoviePlayerViewController` shows Play button and not auto play. Then user click on Play button, MPMoviePlayerViewController must run in FULLScreen by calling `[self presentMoviePlayerViewControllerAnimated:moviePlayer];`. How can i  do that? Thanks in advance.

```
movieURL = [NSURL URLWithString:previewString];

    moviePlayer = [[MPMoviePlayerViewController alloc] initWithContentURL:movieURL];
    moviePlayer.view.frame = CGRectMake(10,130, 275 , 150);
    [moviePlayer.moviePlayer prepareToPlay] ;
    moviePlayer.moviePlayer.shouldAutoplay = NO;
    moviePlayer.wantsFullScreenLayout = NO;
    moviePlayer.moviePlayer.controlStyle = MPMovieControlStyleEmbedded;
    //[detailview addSubview:moviePlayer.view];
    [self presentMoviePlayerViewControllerAnimated:moviePlayer];
```

If tried above code, moviePlayer auto run in FULLSCREEN mode. Now i want when begin, moviePlayer not autorun in FULLSCREEN mode and when user click on Play button, it'll run in FULLSCREEN mode.

Answer (score 1):

Ask to be notified that the playback state has changed:

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                         selector:@selector(mpChangedPlaybackState:)
                                             name:MPMoviePlayerPlaybackStateDidChangeNotification
                                           object:nil];
```

Then check the playback state to see if it's playing:

```
- (void)mpChangedPlaybackState:(NSNotification *)notification {

    if (self.moviePlayer.playbackState == MPMoviePlaybackStatePlaying) {
        // the state has changed to 'playing'
    }
}
```

Remember to remove yourself as an observer when you no longer need to know (at the latest, on `viewWillDisappear:`)

Comment: i tried your code but mpChangedPlaybackState() function is for MPMoviePlayerController not MPMoviePlayerViewController

Comment: The MPMoviePlayerViewController contains a MPMoviePlayerController that posts those notifications.  mpChangedPlaybackState is my made-up name for the method to be fired when the notification is posted.  You can use any name you wish, as long as it matches the addObserver selector.

Comment: I tried - (void)mpChangedPlaybackState:(NSNotification *)notification {
    
    if (moviePlayer.moviePlayer.playbackState == MPMoviePlaybackStatePlaying) {
        // the state has changed to 'playing'
    }
    else
    {
        [self presentMoviePlayerViewControllerAnimated:moviePlayer];
    }
    
}
But it seems works

Comment: It looks like you have just a // comment in the condition.  My comment was to show you were to put code.  Maybe just start with NSLog's in the method and inside the condition.

Comment: I only want to click on Play button, it will call [self presentMoviePlayerViewControllerAnimated:moviePlayer];

Comment: I used my code, movieplayer auto run in FULLSCREEN, so that i want to user click on Play button, it just play video in FULLSCREEN. How can i do that? Thanks so much